# get PHP redirect url

Tags: php, url, curl

I am working on a application that requires me to get the final URL after redirection. I tried different solutions before posting this question but nothing works.

The initial url to query is [Base URL](http://www.epa.gov/myenv/myenview2.find?pQuery=27606). It uses **JS redirection** and redirects to [Redirect URL](http://www.epa.gov/myenv/myenview2.html?minx=-76.97948&miny=38.96742&maxx=-76.78894&maxy=39.03545&ve=12,39.00156,-76.88437&pSearch=20770,%20MD)

is there a way where I can get the final redirected url from the initial url ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`curl_getinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) with opt parameter `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`

From above linked page:

```
CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL - Last effective URL
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a JS redirect. If you look at the JS code of the first page you'll see how it generate the next URL. You can try to implement the same URL generation and get the final URL.

Comment: yes i did see that, but i was just wondering if there's a way to get the final url without all the extra work.